# Pythonで関数にTypeHintをつける場合に引数の型を元にした型を返り値にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか

Tags: python, python3

### 概要

Pythonで関数にTypeHintをつける場合に引数の型を元にした型を返り値にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか

### 詳細

詳細はサンプルコードを見て頂きたいのですが、親クラスAがあり、子クラスB、Cがあります。（実際には子クラスは複数ある）
関数Xは引数としてBを渡すとBのインスタンス、Cを渡すとCのインスタンスを返す実装になります。
その際に関数XにTypeHintをうまくつけるにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

引数、返り値共にAを指定すると意味合い的には合ってはいるものの、Bを渡した際にCが返ってきても意味合い的には間違っていない事になってしまいます。

他の言語ではTなどと書かれる部分と認識しておりますが、どのように書くのが正しいのかわからないため質問させていただきました。

### サンプルコード

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Type
class Drink(ABC):
    pass
class Cola(Drink):
    pass
class Tea(Drink):
    pass
def create_drink(drink: Type[Drink]) -> Drink: # ここのTypeHintを改善したい
    return drink()

# VS Codeなどで見た際にCola型と認識してくれない
created_drink = create_drink(Cola)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typing の TypeVarで他の言語で言うところのTみたいなのが定義できます。

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Drink)
def create_drink(drink: Type[T]) -> T:
    return drink()

created_drink = create_drink(Cola)
```

気になったので補足なのですが、Pythonの型ヒントはあくまでヒントなので実行時になにか影響するわけではないです。
なのでコメントに「#created_drinkの型はDrinkであり、Colaではない」とありますが、Typeヒントがあろうとなかろうと間違っていようとColaのオブジェクトが返ってきます。

```
#元のコード
def create_drink(drink: Type[Drink]) -> Drink: 
    return drink()

created_drink = create_drink(Cola)
print(type(created_drink))  # 出力は→ <class '__main__.Cola'>
```

VSCodeなどのIDEを使うと、TypeHintの定義を見てイイ感じに補完機能が効いたり、警告だしたりしてくれますね。
[image: Colaで補完]

[image: Teaで補完]

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさしくこちらが求めていた答えになります！「Typeヒントがあろうとなかろうと間違っていようとColaのオブジェクトが返ってきます。」こちらはその通りですね。ご記載の通り、VS Codeなどで補完が意図する形にならないという事を言いたかったです。質問も修正しておきます。

Answer (score -1):

クラスの継承との関係であれば、以下のようなコードがPythonだと可能のようです。

```py
class Drink():
    @classmethod
    def create_drink(self):
        return self
        
    def printDrinkType():
        print("Drink")
    
class Cola(Drink):
    def printDrinkType():
        print("Cola")


drink = Drink.create_drink()
drink.printDrinkType() # Drink

cola = Cola.create_drink()
cola.printDrinkType() # Cola
```

Comment: TypeHintの付け方についての質問になります。zundaさんの回答がどのように関連しているのか私にはわかりませんでした。すいません。

Comment: 自分の認識と異なっていたようです。すいません。スルーして大丈夫です。